# FontAwesomeIconView not found in scene builder

Tags: java, javafx

when import jar file in Scene Builder to get *`FontAwesomeIconView .....`*
(for example when import fontawesomefx-8.9.jar.
i have problem to get FontAwesomeIconView in Scene Builder
enter image description here

[image]

Comment: Why do you use an old version? Anyway, importing FontAwesomeFX 8.9 with Scene Builder 8.4.1, I can see `FontAwesomeView` and a bunch of other controls.

Comment: @JoséPereda give me link please

Comment: For Scene Builder? [Here](http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/#download). Note you can install both 8.4.1 (for Java 8) and 9.0.1 for Java 9. With the latter you can install the latest FontAwesomeFX release, which was made for Java 9.